# Difference between orthonormal bases and orthonormal sets

Tags: linear-algebra

I was pretty confused about these two terms: 'orthonormal basis' and 'orthonormal set'. I know the orthonormal basis is just the normalized vectors of the orthogonal basis, but what about the orthonormal set? What

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orthonormal set is not necessarily a basis, that is, the span of the Orthonormal set need not be the entire space.

One example is $\mathbb{R}^3$.
$\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$ is an orthonormal set but not a basis.